# Remove speed ease from animation in Blender 2.5

Tags: animation, blender, blender-2.50

By default Blender adds speed easing to the animation. I need to remove it to get consistent rotation speed on my model. How/Where can I modify ease curve?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to edit the key frame interpolation in the graph editor. Select your object and then choose the graph editor in the selection box at the bottom left of the screen. You can then zoom out using the scroll wheel to see the curve. You are able to edit the points by clicking them with the right mouse button and moving them with the left.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for screenshot, made it easy to understand.